# Is it possible to create object for Runnable interface in java

Tags: java

I can't understand below code to create `Runnable` object.  Could someone please explain clearly what is happening here:

```
public class ThreadStart {
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
      @Override
      public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
          System.out.println(i+" runnable thread...");
        }
      }
    });
    t1.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Check Anonymous class in java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine the following implementation of your `Runnable`. A simple class that implements an interface.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " runnable thread...");
        }
    }
}
```

So, in order to create your `Thread` the way you intended you must provide an implementation of a `Runnable` object. There are various ways to achieve this.

The most straightforward approach is perhaps to use an instance of the `Runnable` from above:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
```

An alternative to that is to provide the `Runnable` directly in the code as an *anonymous inner class* which you can find out more about [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

An anonymous inner class simply means that you create a class as an expression in the code where you mean to use it - the class must follow the same signature (i.e. in this case it implements the `Runnable` interface).

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " runnable thread...");
        }
    }
});
```

From the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

> The anonymous class expression consists of the following:
>
> - The new operator
> - The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend. In this example, the anonymous class is implementing the interface HelloWorld.
> - Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a normal class instance creation expression. Note: When you implement an interface, there is no constructor, so you use an empty pair of parentheses, as in this example.
> - A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.

So, basically what you are doing is passing a `Runnable` to your `Thread` constructor. If you are passing it as an anonymous class you simply pass it as an expression where you actually define your entire inner class.

Furthermore, in Java 8 you can replace the anonymous inner class with a lambda expression like this:

```
Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " runnable thread...");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Wassgren for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

This code creates an instance of an anonymous class (meaning it has no name) that implements the `Runnable` interface. This instance is passed to the constructor of the `Thread` class.

Answer (score 1):

The code uses an anonymous class. You can learn everything about anonymous classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Basically it means that you are going to create a class that implements `Runnable` by implementing the methods directly into your method call.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an instance of an *anonymous inner class* that *implements* the `Runnable` interface. If you go to your directory where the `.class` files will be placed, you can see the anonymous class created with the name `ThreadStart$1.class`. i.e, `OuterClass$1.class`

Answer (score 0):

you use `Anonymous class` that implements `Runnable` interface and be passed into your Thread constructor which accept `Runnable` type

**Anonymous Classes**

Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once.